# extraReducers in redux toolkit is not catching an action

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, redux-toolkit

```
import { createAsyncThunk, createSlice } from '@reduxjs/toolkit';
import request from '../../utils/request';

export const fetchReports = createAsyncThunk(
  'reports/fetchReports',
  async (Criteria, thunkAPI) => {
    const url = '/fetchReport';
    const options = { method: 'POST', data: { Criteria: { ...Criteria } } };
    const response = await request(url, options);
    return response.ReportData;
  },
);

export const clinicReportsSlice = createSlice({
  name: 'reports',
  initialState: {
    reports: {}
  },
  reducers: {
  },
  extraReducers: {
    [fetchReports.fulfilled]: (state, action) => {
      console.log("INFO: Action Called!!") ---------------> not able to see this log
    },
  },
});

export default clinicReportsSlice.reducer;
```

So, I am able to see the action "reports/fetchReports/fulfilled" is called inside the devtools.
but unfortunately for me, it is **not** taking any effect in extraReducers

I have even tried hard coding the action name, which obviously will not make any difference. But still, I tried.

```
'reports/fetchReports/fulfilled': () => {
      console.log('asdf');
 },
```

Can you think of any possible reason why it is not working?

my configuration is like this and it is required for the existing code to work without any errors.

```
export const store = configureStore({
  reducer: allReducers,
  middleware: (getDefaultMiddleware) => {
    console.log(getDefaultMiddleware().concat(apiMiddleware));
    return [getDefaultMiddleware()[1], apiMiddleware];
  },
});
```

Comment: I wonder if your `apiMiddleware` is interfering somehow?  Also `getDefaultMiddleware()[1]` is a little weird because it relies on the order being what you expect.  I would recommend limiting the array by calling  `getDefaultMiddleware` with options. `const basic = getDefaultMiddleware({thunk: true, immutableCheck: false, serializableCheck:false});  return [...basic, apiMiddleware]`.

Comment: Also are you *sure* that is is `fulfilled`?  If you add an extra reducer for the `rejected` action, does that pick up on anything?

Comment: apiMiddleware is just works for the action with type:API, else it will just call next(), I will try that other syntax for getDefaultMiddleware  .

Comment: yes it is fulfilled, I have checked that using console.log(response) right after the API call also I have tried with reject and afterall in dev tools it shows "reports/fetchReports/fulfilled" is getting dispatched.

Comment: Are the actions visible when you look at the DevTools? Also, are you sure you added that reducer to `allReducers`?

Comment: yes, actions are visible in devtools, also I have added the reducer to allReducers which I have exported in the last line. I have tried RTK in a new project and it is working as expected there.

Comment: If you are still looking for an answer, can you migrate your minimal erroneous code to a *runnable* sandbox or git repo (whatever is easy for you)? Or if you have found an answer (probably any *typo*), you can close the question.

Comment: I didn't find any solution to this, so I just commented the RTK setup for now and moving forward with redux without RTK.
yet I will try to create a minimal code setup on sandbox.

Answer (score 2):

I faced this issue when there was a duplicate asyncthunk with same typePrefix.

Can you confirm there's no other asyncthunk using the same action type "reports/fetchReports"?